# Existence of a curve of finite length on the image of a Sobolev embedding

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, sobolev-spaces, surfaces

Suppose that we have an embedding $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^3$ which belongs in the Sobolev space $W^{1,p}_{loc}(\mathbb{R^2},\mathbb{R}^3)$ for some $p>2$. Is it true then that for any two points in $f(R^2)$ there exists a curve of finite length connecting them?

**Fuglede's theorem:** Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R^m}$ is in $W^{1,p}_{loc}$ for any $p$. Then the family of paths which have a closed subpath on which $f$ is not absolutely continuous has $p$-modulus zero.

Added: The modulus of a path family $\Gamma$ is defined to be $M_p(\Gamma)=\inf_{\rho}\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\rho^pdm$, where the infimum is taken over all Borel functions $\rho:\mathbb{R}^2\to[0,\infty]$ such that $\int_\gamma\rho ds\geq 1$ for all locally rectifiable path $\gamma\in \Gamma$.

Comment: Have you got any insight on why this should be true?

Comment: Yes by Fuglede's theorem $f$ is absolutely continuous on almost every path (in the moudulus sense). The image of these paths will have finite length. But this does not give you that all points can be connected by such a path.

Comment: Ok, let's see. Take $p=f(x)$ and $q=f(y)$. Let $\gamma(t)=ty+(1-t)x$. Then $f(\gamma(t))$ connects $p$ and $q$. What is the problem? I suppose it might happen that we have been unlucky and $f(\gamma(t))$ is one of those paths with infinite length.

Comment: I upvoted. Now it is a good question with a fair amount of background. Unfortunately I can't really think of anything except what I already wrote. Is it obvious that the modulus of the set of all paths connecting two given points is zero?

Comment: No you can find a proof in Vaisala's book page 23 Lectures on n-dimensional quasiconformal mappings

Answer (score 0):

**PARTIAL PROGRESS**. As you mention in comments (and you should really edit the question to include this important piece of information), by Fuglede's theorem $f(\gamma(t))$ is absolutely continuous for almost all path $\gamma\colon [0, 1]\to \mathbb R^2$. In particular, $f(\gamma(t))$ is finite length for almost all paths.

Now take $p=f(x)$ and $q=f(y)$. Let
$$\Gamma=\{\gamma\colon [0, 1]\to \mathbb R^2\ :\ \gamma(0)=x, \gamma(1)=y\}.$$
For each $\gamma\in\Gamma$, the path $f(\gamma(t))$ connects $p$ and $q$. The difficulty is that $f(\gamma(t))$ may a priori have infinite length.

So aiming for a contradiction suppose that $f(\gamma(t))$ has infinite length for all $\gamma\in \Gamma$. I do not have the necessary definitions, because you did not explain them, so I cannot continue. (What does "almost all path" mean, exactly? What measure you put on the space of all paths?).

However, my gut feeling is that this must be in contradiction with that Fuglede's theorem mentioned above. For, whatever that "almost all path" means, I doubt that $\Gamma$ has measure zero. Therefore there must be at least one path $\gamma$ in $\Gamma$ such that $f(\gamma(t))$ is absolutely continuous.

Comment: No that does not work beacause $\Gamma$ has zero modulus. The modulus of all paths connecting two points is zero.

Comment: Well, then I don't know. Why don't you spend a few more words in the question? You may mention the Fuglede theorem, it's not something that everybody knows.